# In RallyDev, how to get Epic "Plan Est" summary to be sensitive to the selected view or filter?

Tags: rally

The best way to explain my problem is through a picture:

[image]

I have a custom view setup which basically filters to a combination of releases.  When I view it, the "Plan Est" values on the Epics (parent stories in the hierarchy) don't total to the points assigned to the stories contained in the view.  They add up to the total of all child stories across the whole program.

The weird thing is that the Plan Est at the top of the view IS what I want.  It only contains the sum total of the stories selected in the view.

I need to report on totals at the epic level too often to add these up manually every time.

Anybody know if there is a way to have to tool calculate these for me?

If not, does anybody have guidance on a tool I can try out?

Or is there some API solution I can investigate to get these totals?  I've not scratched the surface on the API.

---

On edit, this is what I mean by "View"
[image]

Comment: When you say view are you referring to the Project the stories are tied to?

Comment: The PlanEstimate field on epics is a rollup- this is a static calculated number which is not affected by a query.  The only way to get this would be through the API, retrieving all leaf stories that match a given set of release filters and then totalling those up manually...

Comment: James, I updated my post above to explain what I mean by view.  The same problem applies to filters though